# Naming Convention for ServiceStack DTO's

Tags: servicestack

I know this has been asked to some degree already - and is a fairly subjective question. I’m trying to figure out the best naming convention for a set of services that we are porting over to ServiceStack from WCF. I have read through a lot of the ServiceStack documentation and examples – and I feel I have a pretty good understanding of the overall structure. What I am trying to work out is the best naming convention for my request and response DTO’s.

Let me give some examples. Here would be my request dto as I have currently named it.

```
[Route("/blast/emailblast", "POST")]
public class CreateEmailBlast : IReturn<CreateCreateEmailBlastResponse>  
{
    public Guid SenderProfileId { get; set; }
    public Guid TemplateId { get; set; }
    public string CallListName { get; set; }
    public string CallListCategory { get; set; }    
}

public class CreateEmailBlastResponse : ICreateEmailBlastResponse
{
    public string ResponseMessage { get; set; }
}
```

So the naming I have adopted is prefix the dto with "Create" for posts, "Get" for Gets, etc... Would it be wiser to just use EmailBlast and EmailBlastResponse? Just wondering if anyone has some input on these two different methods of naming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will be wiser to use EmailBlast only. As, http verbs are there to identify what is going to happen.

If you are looking at how to design good API. (General purpose, not specifically with SS). There is a wonderful video over [infoq](http://infoq.com). I couldn't remember the name over top of mind.

But gist of the that presentation was , *try to think of API as user facing html page*. What you need at user end. And I can go a little bit more to that, define model after deciding page. To do specifically that, there is a need of metadata.

Means, there is a EmailBlast model, how can I tell to create. So, instead of CreateEmailBlast model, I will go with http post verb. Here, I am trying to take simple example.

Personally I will try to avoid Hungarian notation for variable as well as for model wherever I can.

Please let  me know if I understand you question correctly and also if you need any further details from my end.

Comment: Yeah that is the direction that I was going. Just saw some example code on the ServiceStack Wiki that used the prefixes liked that.

Comment: @MikeSchwartz that would be special case / or  demo purpose only. In most of the cases it will be for demo purpose. I personally don't like to use prefix or post-fix